# Evaluating Rails 4 validations on conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let's say I have an ActiveRecord model with some validations.

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :title
  validates_uniqueness_of :slug
end
```

I'm looking for a way to put conditions on whether or not the validations are evaluated with the creation or update of an object of this model.

Would something like this work?

```
#pseudocode
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  if conditions
      validates_presence_of :title
      validates_uniqueness_of :slug
  end
end
```

Is there a best practice for this? Or is this whole approach a faux pas?

Comment: see the email example http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the available [Common Validation Options](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#common-validation-options), if they suffice your conditional requirement. 
BUT if you have some specific conditions in mind, then check the [Conditional Validation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation)
part specified in ROR Guides.

Comment: One example I was thinking of when I asked the question was that I'd like to perform validations normally, but skip some validations when working in rails console.

Comment: This answer helps and totally applies, but what's your opinion on the example I gave for an environmental condition?

Comment: `rails console` is not a separate environment. The console command lets you interact with your Rails application from the command line. On the underside, rails console uses IRB, so if you've ever used it, you'll be right at home. This is useful for testing out quick ideas with code and changing data server-side without touching the website.

Comment: Perhaps environment was the wrong word. I got what I was looking for. I put my validations around a conditional which evaluates to true if the console is not being used, thereby skipping validations when in console. Thanks for your help.